# mb_strlen() is it enough?

Tags: php, utf-8, multilingual, mbstring

When counting the length of an UTF-8 string in PHP I use `mb_strlen()`.

For example:

```
if (mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8') < 3) {
    $error .= 'Name is required. Minimum of 3 characters required in name.';
}
```

As the text fields can accept any language (multilanguage), I want to make sure that PHP will count mutltilanguage UTF-8 characters correctly.

Is this sufficient or do I need to use other methods? I am concerned PHP may get it wrong for some reason, or maybe I am just being skeptical, but I don't want people bypassing important validation because PHP is getting it wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Correct**

```
if (mb_strlen($name, 'UTF-8') < 3) is sufficient enough
```

make sure header is correct

```
HTTP-header (Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8)
```

you can also check alternative for some reason

```
strlen(utf8_decode($string))
```

[UTF-8 to Code Point Array Converter in PHP](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/)

Comment: Thanks JapanPro.

My HTTP-header is fine thank you.

Will check that link out. So i guess mb_strlen() can be trusted then as my http header is as you have said above?

Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that in Dutch there are names with 2 characters: An and Japanese names can also have only 2 chararcters. 林田 (hayashida) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **JapanPro's** answer:
Your HTML can have :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

instead of an implicit header declaration:

```
HTTP-header (Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8)
```